# PHP/Wordpress, Childthemes and functions already defined

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wordpress-theming

I'm wondering (I have full access to the serve in case it's a php.ini setting) if there's anyway to "disable parsing of functions if a function was already defined" instead of throwing an error/notice about it?

For example /www/main/deep/file/file.php has:

```
function homepage_filter_get_map () {

    // example1
    $generic_filter_array = td_generic_filter_array::get_array();

    }
```

and in /www/main-child/custom.php has, which is called/included/parsed before the file above:

```
function homepage_filter_get_map () {

    //do nothing

    }
```

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to suppress any and all errors outputting about already defined functions while silently ignoring functions that might have the same exact name, but already parsed/defined.

My problem is that the theme I'm using doesn't have full support for Wordpress child themes, just loop files mainly. I know I can just tweak the original files but I want the ability to be able to keep the theme updated without erasing all of our custom tweaks every-time.

**Note:** Yes, I know you can conditionally call functions, but again I'm looking for a way to do this without editing any of the "main" files since any tweaks done to those get overwritten when updating the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(function_exists('homepage_filter_get_map'))){
    function homepage_filter_get_map(){
        //do code
    }
}
```

This checks if the function 'homepage_filter_get_map' exists. If it doesn't, create the function.

Comment: Yea, but that's the "proper" way to do it. What I'm looking to do is  have 2 files with the same function name, but file1.php has the original and file2.php has the updated one. Both files are called, file2.php is called first though. I don't want to touch file1.php but if a function exists in file2.php I want that one to be used and any resulting errors/notices to be discarded when file1.php gets parsed and it says "function already defined". It's the only way it can be done until the theme developers change ALL existing functions in ALL files to be child-theme compatible.

Comment: This sounds to me like you could just create two separate functions. I guess I'm a little confused still by your request.